# Write a text file on VS Built

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, msbuild

I want to write a text file in a VS build that contains
a newly created guid.
The writing of the file works, but how do I get a guid into it?

Like this (this dont work):

```
Guid x = System.Guid.NewGuid();
echo x >> file.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this task to your `csproj` file. This will create new guid and save it to `guid.txt` using [WriteLinesToFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/writelinestofile-task) task. It also supports different formats of result with [`ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tostring)

```xml
  <Target Name="SaveGuidToSomeFile" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <WriteLinesToFile File="guid.txt" Lines="$([System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString('d'))" Overwrite="true" />
  </Target>
```

`Overwrite="true"` required to overwrite file instead of appending which is default